# How to find Number of parameters of a keras model?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

For a Feedforward Network (FFN), it is easy to compute the number of parameters. Given a CNN, LSTM etc is there a quick way to find the number of parameters in a keras model?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Models and layers have special method for that purpose:

```
model.count_params()
```

Also, to get a short summary of each layer dimensions and parameters, you might find useful the following method

```
model.summary()
```

Comment: Notice, that is the count for total, trainable and non-trainable parameters.

Answer (score 15):

```
import keras.backend as K

def size(model): # Compute number of params in a model (the actual number of floats)
    return sum([np.prod(K.get_value(w).shape) for w in model.trainable_weights])
```

Answer (score 5):

Tracing back the `print_summary()` function, Keras developers compute the number of trainable and non_trainable parameters of a given `model` as follows:

```
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np

trainable_count = int(np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.trainable_weights)]))

non_trainable_count = int(np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.non_trainable_weights)]))
```

Given that `K.count_params()` is defined as `np.prod(int_shape(x))`, this solution is quite similar to the one of Anuj Gupta, except for the use of `set()` and the way the shape of the tensors are retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your network add:   model.summary
And it will give you a summary of your network and the number of parameters.